# Ldap Search on the host server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, openldap

I developed a small C++ application to bind a user in a server using `active directory` then return the name of his group.
The probleme is when I run the application from a remote computer, it run with no probleme. When I try to run it at the host server, -the computer hosting the `active directory`- the binding process pass, but the searching function always return `Operation error`: this is a sample of my code.

```
 if ((rc = ldap_simple_bind_s( ld, loginDN, password )) != LDAP_SUCCESS )
{
    printf("ldap_simple_bind_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string( rc ));
    ldap_unbind_s( ld );
    return 10;
}
printf("Bind and authentication to the server successful\n");

string a="(&(objectclass=person)(cn="+prenom+" "+nom+"))";
rc = ldap_search_ext_s(
            ld,                    /* LDAP session handle */
            searchBase,            /* container to search */
            LDAP_SCOPE_ONELEVEL,   /* search scope */
            a.c_str(),             /*search filter*/
            NULL,                  /* return all attributes */
            0,                     /* return attributes and values */
            NULL,                  /* server controls */
            NULL,                  /* client controls */
            &timeOut,              /* search timeout */
            LDAP_NO_LIMIT,         /* no size limit */
            &searchResult );       /* returned results */
if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS )
{
    cout<<rc<<endl;
    printf("ldap_search_ext_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string( rc ));
    ldap_msgfree( searchResult );
    ldap_unbind_s( ld );
    return  20 ;
}
```

Comment: Please capitalize and puncuate this mess.

Comment: @EJP Sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I must use the port `3268` instead of `389`